# Passing a class as a parameter in a method and using this parameter in an If statement

Tags: java, class, runtime-type

I would like to have something like this:

```
public static List<Type> getProtocolls(Class clazz, Transaction trx) {
    Iterator<Type> iterator = trx.getContext().getProtocolls()
    List<Type> list = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next() instanceof clazz) {
            list.add(iterator.next())
        }       
    }
    return list;
}
```

I am talking mainly about this part: `(iterator.next() instanceof clazz)` - is this even possible to pass Class as a parameter like this? Eclipse says "clazz cannot be resolved to a type".

Comment: Try with `if (iterator.next() instanceof clazz,class) {`

Comment: @SaviNuclear - not working at all :(

Comment: Sidenote: You should instantiate your list before using it. But that's not the solution to your instanceof-problem.

Comment: `instanceof  Class` instead of `clazz`

Comment: `if (iterator.next() instanceof Class ) {`

Comment: You should also use the generic version `Class<?>` instead `Class`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`isAssignableFrom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-) method. Also, note you have two calls to `next()` in the loop, so you'll be skipping half the elements - you should extract the result of this call to a local variable:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Type t = iterator.next();
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(t.getClass())) {
        list.add(t)
    }       
}
```

**EDIT:**

As @Fildor noted in the comments, you also forgot to initialized `list`. Instead of initializing to `null` list you currently have, you should have something down the lines of `List<Type> list = new LinkedList<>();`.

Comment: And his `list` is `null`.

Comment: You can also use `if (clazz.isInstance(t))`

Answer (score -1):

You have mention the reference but you have to use the Class there :-

```
public static List<Type> getProtocolls(Class clazz, Transaction trx) {
    Iterator<Type> iterator = trx.getContext().getProtocolls()
    List<Type> list = null;
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next() instanceof Class ) {
            list.add(iterator.next())
        }       
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: He does not know the class up front. This is why the dynamic instanceof `clazz.isAssignableFrom()` has to be used here.